# Which tools are most likely used to create animated video (i.e. corporate commercials)?

Tags: video, software-recommendation, animation

Animated video is sometimes very well done and extremely attractive and captivating. I would like to know what tools are typically used to create this kind of video. I specifically have in mind the kind of animation typically used in corporate training or commercials. [Here's an example:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6MmMJi1oII)

Answer (score 2):

I can't be really sure, but most of that can be done using After Effects and a simple screen recording. You record the screen of a phone, put that into after effects, get a picture of a hand and put that into after effects, and just move it around with the frames.

The whole of screen recording could also be made using Adobe Flash or After Effects instead of actually taking it, but it would take a while... This way you could create a minimal and simple version of your app or something, which might be more eye-pleasing and less complicated to the audience.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Mac user, Apple have a motion graphics suite called Motion 5 which is available for $49.99 USD. There are some templates that come with it and many commercial templates can be purchased and customised. In my experience, Motion excels in very short, but snazzy animations and is quite resource intensive.

After Effects is one of the most popular animation programs. It is an Adobe product that works on both Windows and Mac and can be used with a license that costs $20 USD / month.

A free alternative to both of these is a 3D software called Blender which can also make 2d animations. It is open-source software and works on Mac, Windows and Linux. It is available at https://blender.org

However, it is arguably more suited to technically minded users and may be frustrating to learn how to use. It is an incredibly powerful though and feature rich.